# TensorFlow：How to calculate the Euclidean distance between two tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKalb.png)

How to get from A and B to C? A and B are tensors and belong to the output of the network. Now I need to get C from the output operation of the two networks, and then use C to calculate loss function.

The key problem is to optimize A and B by loss function in the later stage, so it must be completed in the form of computational graphs. The TensorFlow formulas for calculating tensors don't seem to be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`tf.norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm):

```
C = tf.norm(B - A, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Create The Tensors
pt_a = tf.constant([5., 10.,11.])
pt_b = tf.constant([8., 3.,12.])

#Print Euclidean Distance
print("Euclidean Distance:",tf.norm(pt_a-pt_b,ord='euclidean'))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Consider adding an explanation of how your code answers the problem/question. Code-only answers are often less useful for people new to the language or topic.

Comment: Define the points as tensor constants and use the tensor norm function to determine the euclidean distance.